# Close chosen applications upon game launch

Tags: windows, process

How to automatically quit/close choosen applications upon game launch in Windows Vista x64 Ultimate?

For example, if I want to launch a game from Steam, and want another chosen applications to automatically quit. I don't need any GUI of that "application" when launching a game, just select a game from Steam, start play, and other unneeded applications/processes to automatically quit. I don't want to use any keystrokes or keyboard keys for that. I need it to automatically end processes when launching a game.

Or the same purpose tool might be like this: automatically close applications on game launch detect.

Does "Game Booster PRO or Free" do this? I don't want many programs or processes to quit. I just want several selected Windows applications to quit when launching a game. And I don't want bother with GUI or Game Booster GUI when launching a game from Steam or desktop shortcut. Just silently do the "close application" job when launching a game from Steam or desktop shortcut.

Comment: sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

Simple scripts can do that. the command "taskkill" can be applied even using various wildcards.
http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/446/xp_kill_windows_process_command_line_taskkill/
This location gives you some ideas on things you can try with that, using a CMD prompt.

This is the freeware program that will close the explorer windows, and send a close to other windows you specify in the ini file .  easy to work with.
http://leeos.tripod.com/index-14.html
Closing time Closetm.exe.
It does not always work with all programs, but it closing all the open folders alone is very handy.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html
 nircmd could also be applied, it might be more work than needed.  and PM.exe  CMD version of the ProcessMonitor program from systemexternals.

If your going to close things, It is always preferable to close other thing first before running the next one (clear out of memory). So you could script things to close then run the game in the same script.  But I find that having a script or program that just shuts stuff down that is unneeded and runs with one click (shortcut) can be used independently for more than just games.

Comment: but these programs are not active, i mean not in system tray?

Comment: None of the methods that I stated would be active and watching, just manuel quick ways to close stuff. Having something activly watching would defeat the purpose of having nothing (or less) running.  If you want the whole computer dedicated to playing a game (for example) then that is accomplished by stopping stuff, not adding one more thing to the mess.